# Angular4+ show/hide child element in HTML template

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to implement a simple "hover on a comment to show a reply button" implementation in my angular application. Is there a way to achieve this effect by using template reference variables only?

Something along the lines of...

```
<mat-list>
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let comment of comments" #SomeRefToThisParticularElement (mouseenter)="SomeRefToThisParticularElement=true" (mouseleave)="SomeRefToThisParticularElement=false">
    <h4>{{comment.text}}</h4>
    <p> 3 replies </p>
    <mat-icon *ngIf="SomeRefToThisParticularElement==true">reply</mat-icon>
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

Obviously, the above doesn't work cause angular won't let you assign or set template variables the way I have shown in the snippet above. But I would like to explore options to achieve this at the html template level.

Is this a good approach to do this?

**Edit**
Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49234261/2809541) for a summary of possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, Hide and show based on the hover index of an array.

```
<mat-list>
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let comment of comments; let i = index" (mouseenter)="commentIndex= i" (mouseleave)="commentIndex = -1">
        <h4 mat-line>{{comment.text}}</h4>
        <p mat-line style="font-size:x-small; color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54)"> 3 replies </p>
        <mat-icon *ngIf="commentIndex == i">reply</mat-icon>
    </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

Comment: Yup, this is perfect. Occam's Razor!

Answer (score 0):

Use a  dynamic object to do this, like `comment.isVisible`. Now the `isVisible` object is dynamically created and it will be modify the value while hover in/out.

Please try this way

```
<mat-list>
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let comment of comments" (mouseenter)="comment.isVisible = true" (mouseleave)="comment.isVisible= false" >
    <h4 mat-line >{{comment.text}}</h4>
    <p mat-line style="font-size:x-small; color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54)"> 3 replies </p>
    <mat-icon *ngIf="comment.isVisible">reply</mat-icon>
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

Comment: Since I am dealing with an immutable object - "comments", any modifications to the underlying object is going to be my last resort. But this is a good solution too. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. [Simplest Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49233945/2809541) (Credit: [Rahul Sharma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8879527/rahul-sharma)) - use index of the element and set that as the value of a dynamic variable that is used within an *ngIf statement for show/hide behavior of an element.
2. [Next Best Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49233788/2809541) (Credit: [Ramesh Rajendran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2218635/ramesh-rajendran)) - Add a dynamic property to the iterable object. This assumes that the iterable object is not immutable.

Thanks to the respective contributors. Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

you can use css:

```
mat-icon{
    color: transparent;
} 
mat-icon:hover, mat-icon:active{
    color:black;
}
```

Comment: That will trigger the show/hide behavior for each element and not just the specific one being hovered on. Also, changing the colors would still risk exposing other events registered on that element such as click. That would be an anti-pattern.